# How to detect if form submit worked htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to webscrape data from [marinetraffic.com](http://marinetraffic.com). It's a pretty simple form:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="login_form_REACT" class="text-left ws-validate" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    ...
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Email" name="data[email]">
    ...
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control user-error" required="" placeholder="Password" name="data[password]">
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[remember]" id="remember2" value="1">
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary vertical-offset-10 btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</div>
</form>
```

What I have so far:

```
String username = "username@gmail.com";
String password = "fake_password";

WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

HtmlPage webPage = (HtmlPage)client.getPage("https://www.marinetraffic.com/");
HtmlForm loginForm = (HtmlForm)webPage.getElementById("login_form_REACT");

loginForm.getInputByName("data[email]").setValueAttribute(username);
loginForm.getInputByName("data[password]").setValueAttribute(password);

((HtmlButton)loginForm.getFirstByXPath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
```

I printed the resulting webpage, and it was just the same webpage but with the form filled in. I'm not sure how to test whether or not the post request went out with the button click.

Is there some way I can detect outgoing HTTP requests with HtmlUnit? Or any suggestion as to why this webpage is not letting me log in? Not sure if this is relevant information, but MarineTraffic does a page refresh instead of page redirect during login.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Simply enable HttpClient wire logging.

Comment: Am I doing this right? I'm following [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html), and I copied and pasted the arguments into the JVM run settings. I turned the logger on for only the line of code I want to test, but the only thing printing is **WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'**.